# find album art and cover art programatically in Android

Tags: java, android, gracenote, albumart

I have song name, artist name and album name.
Is there any link from where I can get cover or album art by sending these parameters?
For my application I need cover art. I searched a lot to find out something but get nothing.

If there is any third party available for this, then help me with sample code.

By using **Gracenote API**, I am getting song name, artist name and album name but am unable to get cover art. So I need help for this. If I externally can get the cover art by using third party service then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's bit late to answer but you can get the link of the cover art in gracenote response itself but you need to change some properties in its API.
In initGracenote() change following

```
config.setProperty("content.coverart", "1");
```

I also recommend you to set this property also because sometimes I personally felt something chaotic in getting link.

```
config.setProperty("content.allowfullresponse", "1");
```

for fetching coverart URL from response do the following

```
String coverArt = response.getCoverArt().getUrl().toString();
```

Hope it help you.